# How to set custom User-Agent in Paw?

Tags: user-agent, paw-app

By default, Paw sets the User-Agent to something like `Paw/2.3.4 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.6) GCDHTTPRequest`. Is there any way to tweak that for testing purposes? I know I can just use `curl`, but I really like Paw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to tweak the `User-Agent`, you can just change it like any other request header.

1. Click on "Headers" in the Request Composer in Paw. (This should be under the URL bar.)
2. Click on 'Add Header Name' and enter `User-Agent`.
3. Click on 'Add Value' and enter your desired `User-Agent`, or leave it blank.

Comment: D'oh, didn't even think of that. Thanks!